# Making 3D "wall" from elevation points using ArcGIS 3D Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, elevation, 3d-analyst, arcscene, 3d-map

I went for a jog around the block using my GARMIN GPS.  Then, I downloaded the GPX file and converted it to a feature class.  The attributes for the points contain lat/lon & elevation (feet).

[image: My Garmin Data]

I am trying to accomplish the following using the ArcGIS 3D Analyst extension:

[image]

I'm not certain, but I need to:

- Convert the points to a polyline with **retaining** all the elevation
- Extrude the line in ArcScene so it displays as a 3D wall.

As you can see, the base height for the wall is all the same, because it's displayed as dark blue.  As the elevation changes, the colors become lighter.

I have access to all the extensions (3D Analyst, etc).

Comment: what data format are your coordinates in?

Comment: Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_WGS_1984
Datum:  D_WGS_1984
Prime Meridian:  Greenwich
Angular Unit:  Degree

Comment: thats good know as well but I meant like are they in a shapefile? csv? kml? gpx?

Comment: Are you using the ArcGIS 3D Analyst extension?

Comment: The original data is in a .gpx format, but then I convert it to a feature class.

Yes, I am using ArcGIS 3D Analyst extension.

Comment: if its in a points feature class with the z values. then use the points to line tool (make sure to have z values enabled). then I would bring it into arcscene try and extrude it

Comment: or what you can do: download a raster/dem of your jog area and use the interpolate shape tool